# SVN public DNS access problem

Tags: windows, svn

I met a problem on Subversion configuring behind an Apache under the windows.
The server is in domain. If make a check out with the local DNS from the server via HTTPS
I have no a problem , if I (or someone else outside from the company) tries make checkout by specifying the public DNS via HTTPS failed by saying : 
[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/028c3eebd7.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/028c3eebd7.jpg)

This is not Tortoise issure , because the same problem I got from command line too.

Comment: Check that there's nothing in your httpd.conf actually forbidding access from the outside. Also some proxy servers may have issues the PROPFIND method

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your firewall allows exception for the needed ports in external use.
Probably there is something like "allow in domain network" set to that rule, you must change this in order to get it working from outside. But be careful with Windows-Server accessible in the internet.